# c++ "Does not name type" when instantiating inside of namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am trying to use namespace to segment pieces of my code and re-use some names.  When I create a new namespace, It seems the compiler loses the scope to my classes defined outside of that namespace.

I get the following error in `UI_SHARED.h`

> Error  'EZUI_Control_Label' does not name a type

This code works fine without the namespace definition. Do the objects inside the namespace somehow lose access to included files / class definitions?

**UI_SHARED.h**

```
#ifndef __UI_SHARED_H__
#define __UI_SHARED_H__

#include "EZUI_Control_Label.h"

namespace UI_SHARED{
    EZUI_Control_Label Shared_Lbl_HLT("HLT:");
    EZUI_Control_Label Shared_Lbl_MLT("MLT:");
    EZUI_Control_Label Shared_Lbl_BK("BK:");
}

#endif
```

**EZUI_Control_Lable.h**

```
#ifndef __EZUI_CONTROL_LABEL_H__
#define __EZUI_CONTROL_LABEL_H__

//Includes
#include "EZUI_Control.h"
#include "../EZUI.h"

//Forward Declarations
class EZUI;

class EZUI_Control_Label : public EZUI_Control
{
//variables
public:
    using EZUI_Control::Type;
    enum EZUI_Control_Label_Type {None, LblString, LblFloat, LblDouble, LblInt, LblUInt, LblLong, LblULong, LblBool, LblBoolWithText, LblDigitalIO};
    EZUI_Control_Label_Type Label_Type = None;  //Not initialized to any value

protected:
private:
    //When was this last printed.  Used to refresh page
    unsigned long timeLastPrinted = -1;
    void* ItemRef = NULL;
    String blnTrueTxt = "";
    String blnFalseTxt = "";

//functions
public:

    //Over-ridden base class functions
    String Text(void) const  override;
    boolean isSelectable() const override { return false; };
    void Select(EZUI *UI) const override { /* Do nothing */ };

    //Destructor
    ~EZUI_Control_Label() override {};

    //Instantiate - Static Values
    EZUI_Control_Label(char val[]);
    //EZUI_Control_Label(const char val[]);

    //Instantiate - Dynamic Values
    EZUI_Control_Label(float *val);
    EZUI_Control_Label(double *val);
    EZUI_Control_Label(int *val);
    EZUI_Control_Label(unsigned int *val);
    EZUI_Control_Label(long *val);
    EZUI_Control_Label(unsigned long *val);
    EZUI_Control_Label(boolean *val, String TrueText, String FalseText);
    EZUI_Control_Label(DigitalIO *val);

protected:
private:
    //EZUI_Control_Label( const EZUI_Control_Label &c );
    //EZUI_Control_Label& operator=( const EZUI_Control_Label &c ) override;

}; //EZUI_Control_Lablel

#endif //__EZUI_CONTROL_LABLEL_H__
```

Comment: Does one of the other include files ("EZUI_Control.h", "../EZUI.h") include "UI_SHARED.h"?

Comment: Where is the code associated with the error message?

Comment: The Error occurs in the 3 EZUI_Control_Label instantiations inside UI_Shared.h

Neither EZUI_Control.h or EZUI.h include UI_SHARED.h

Comment: Pardon my naivety, but where do you put `EZUI_Control_Label` in any namespace?  I don't see a `namespace` statement in the `EZUI_Control_Lable.h` file.

Comment: I do not, which is why im confused.  Its when I try and define instances of that class inside a namespace (UI_SHARED) when I run into trouble.

Comment: Could you, just to exclude the possibility of an include conflict, add a `class EZUI_Control_Label;` forward declaration between the include guard and the `#include "EZUI_Control_Label.h"` in UI_SHARED.h? And then post the error message.

Comment: I can see the following spelling errors in your post: EZUI_Control_Lable vs EZUI_Control_Label vs EZUI_Control_Lablel. Are you sure that your error is not due to such a typo?

Comment: Thanks all for your help.  It was a circular reference problem, one i added the forward class declaration class EZUI_Control_Label, the problem went away.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help. It was a circular reference problem, one i added the forward class declaration class EZUI_Control_Label, the problem went away. Thanks again.

I also removed the UI_SHARED namespace as I determined it wasnt needed for what I was trying to accomplish.  I didnt re-test with the forward declaration and the shared namespace unfortunately, but I believe the root of my problem was not being able to find the class declaration.